# How to pass many to many object from view

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to post set of keywords in the form submission. When there is the field is empty or the data is null the controller accept it but when i am trying to submit with filled form data its throwing error saying "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." with the error code of "400".
Its very hard for me to trace the error whether its on my controller or in the view?

I have included the controller, model and view of my code. Thank you in advance

campaign class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAMPAIGN")
public class Campaign implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private String campaignId;

@Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
private String name;

@Column(name = "CLIENT_ID", length = 50)
private String clientId;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "START_DATE")
private Date startDate;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "END_DATE")
private Date endDate;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "CAMPAIGN_KEYWORDS", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "CAMPAIGN_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "KEYWORD_ID", referencedColumnName = "VALUE", nullable = false)})
private List<KeyWord> keywords;
```

Keyword Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KEYWORD")
public class KeyWord  implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "VALUE")
private String value;
@Column(name = "TYPE")
private String type;
@Column(name = "STATUS")
private String status;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "keywords")
private List<Campaign> Campaigns;
```

Controller Class

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false, defaultValue = "0") String id) {
        Campaign campaign;
        if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        {
            campaign = new Campaign();
        }
        else{
            campaign = campaignDao.getCampaignById(id);
        }
        List<KeyWord> keyWordList = keyWordDoa.getAllKeywords();
        model.addAttribute("campaign", campaign);
        model.addAttribute("keyWordList", keyWordList);
        return campaignURL + "edit";
    }
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value = "campaign") Campaign campaign, HttpServletRequest request) {

        if(campaign.getCampaignId() == null)
        {
            String id = GenerateID.getID();
            campaign.setCampaignId(id);
            campaign.setUrl(id);
        }
        campaignDao.addCampaign(campaign);


        return "redirect:/campaign";
    }
```

Thymeleaf  view

```
<form th:action="@{/campaign/edit}" method="post" th:object="${campaign}"
                                      enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="form-label">Campaign ID</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="form-control"
                                                   th:field="*{campaignId}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="form-label">Name</label>
                                        <span class="help">e.g. "Red Bull"</span>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"
                                                   placeholder="Red Bull">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="form-label">User Group</label>
                                        <span class="help">Select The User group who has access</span>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <select class="multi" style="width:100%" th:field="*{clientId}">
                                                <option th:each="keyWord : ${keyWordList}"
                                                        th:value="${keyWord}" th:text="${keyWord.value}">Credit
                                                    card
                                                </option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label">Start Date</label>
                                            <span class="help">"YYYY/MM/DD"</span>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <div class="input-append success date">
                                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" th:field="*{startDate}">
                                                    <span class="add-on"><span class="arrow"></span>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-th"></i></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label">End Date</label>
                                            <span class="help">"YYYY/MM/DD"</span>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <div class="input-append success date">
                                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" th:field="*{endDate}">
                                                    <span class="add-on"><span class="arrow"></span>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-th"></i></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="form-label">Keywords</label>
                                        <span class="help">e.g. "Energy, Drink, RedBull"</span>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <select class="multi" style="width:100%" multiple th:field="*{keywords}" th:items>
                                                <option th:each="keyWord : ${keyWordList}"
                                                        th:value="${keyWord}" th:text="${keyWord.value}">Credit card
                                                </option>

                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <button class="btn  btn-default btn-cons" onclick="something()">Cancel
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-cons" type="submit">Save</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Comment: did you try with th:value="${keyWord.value}"?

Comment: Can you add more details of the error showing?